# MySQL equivalent of PHP's base_convert?

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know of an equivalent function in MySQL of PHP's base_convert?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CONV(N,from_base,to_base)
> ```
>
> Converts numbers between different number bases. Returns a string representation of the number `N`, converted from base `from_base` to base `to_base`. Returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`. The argument `N` is interpreted as an integer, but may be specified as an integer or a string. The minimum base is `2` and the maximum base is `36`. If `from_base` is a negative number, `N` is regarded as a signed number. Otherwise, `N` is treated as unsigned. `CONV()` works with 64-bit precision.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv

Comment: How come I get different results from PHP and MySQL with same parameters? number: `d038889e4ba0f254d1e80d275871499064a93c72` from_base: `16` to_base: `36` expected output: `oblzbbrzki88k40wgg8go8w8sscswss` mysql output: `3W5E11264SGSF`

Comment: OK, my bad. MySQL CONV doesn't work for numbers greater than 2^64. But instead of giving an error, it just trims the number in some way.

Comment: I get `FVVVVVVVVVVVV` in my 5.5 server :-?

Comment: Which is also wrong. Using numbers larger than 2^64 is probably undefined behaviour hence different MySQL versions may give different results.

Comment: Yeah... "interpreted as an integer" probably means that limits listed at [Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) apply. I'd expect at least either NULL or a warning but, of course, data integrity has never been the strong point of MySQL Server.

Comment: The maximum base is 36. I need base 62. And string back to int.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [CONV(N,from_base,to_base)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv)